# How to set an object type field in jsp from jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an object type field in my jsp. I want to set the value of the object type field through jQuery. I tried this But didn't work.dataset is the object type field.datasetTable is the name of the table

```
$("#datasetTable input:checked").each(function(index) {
    var attributeId = $(this).val();
    var attributeValue = (this).closest('tr').find('input[type="text"]').val();
    alert(attributeId);
    alert(attributeValue);

    var completeList = {};
    completeList.attributeId = [];
    completeList.attributeId.push({
        attributeValue: attributeValue
    });
});

$('#dataList').val(completeList);                                     `
```

Comment: How this is a spring-mvc question?

Comment: `(this)` should be `$(this)`. You also appear to have created a scope issue with your `completeList` variable.

Comment: i get the following error : ReferenceError: completeList is not defined. Please Help. if this cannot work please suggest a way

Comment: @nishant you define completeList within the .each function, but then later attempt to refer to it outside that function, and therefore outside the scope in which the variable was defined. I suggest you read up on variable scoping, but in the meantime you just need to move `var completeList = {};` before the start of the .each function.